# Could not find matching constructor for: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException

Tags: rest, groovy, httpresponse

I hit an error which says: "Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)" when running code below. Am I missing something? Thanks!

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator
class callmpgPortout implements Runnable {
      // Input variables
      String MSISDN;
      Date REQUEST_START_TIME;
      String NP_TXN_ID;
      String PORT_ID;
      String LOG_ID;
      String OLO;
      String VARIABLE1;
      String VARIABLE2;
      String VARIABLE3;
      String VARIABLE4;
      String VARIABLE5;

      // Output variables
      String MSGCODE;
      String MSGDESC;

      private Long status;
      public void run() {
        def client = new RESTClient('http://sgbdcmpweb01:7980')
            client.handler.failure = { resp, data ->
            resp.setData(data)
            String headers = ""
            resp.headers.each {
                headers = headers+"${it.name} : ${it.value}\n"
            }
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp.getStatus(),"HTTP call failed. Status code: ${resp.getStatus()}\n${headers}\n"+
                                            "Response: "+(resp as HttpResponseDecorator).getData())
            return resp
        }
        def resp = client.post(
              path : '/RTDM/rest/runtime/decisions/mpgPortout',
              requestContentType : ContentType.JSON,
              body: [ version:'1', correlationId:'91', clientTimeZone:'GMT', inputs: [MSISDN:'MSISDN',REQUEST_START_TIME:'REQUEST_START_TIME',NP_TXN_ID:'NP_TXN_ID',PORT_ID:'PORT_ID',LOG_ID:'LOG_ID',OLO:'OLO',VARIABLE1:'VARIABLE1',VARIABLE2:'VARIABLE2',VARIABLE3:'VARIABLE3',VARIABLE4:'VARIABLE4',VARIABLE5:'VARIABLE5'] ]
        )
        status = resp.status;
      }
      public Long getStatus() {
        return status;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one constructor for groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException and it only accepts a groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator (i.e. resp in your sample).